# Parsing a large JSON file for creating wordpress posts

Tags: php, json, wordpress, memory-management

I have a large JSON file (>100MB) which I want to parse and then convert its objects into wordpress posts.
I have successfully created a function to complete this task but it is not able to loop through all object, else it dies by giving an error of PHP Fatal error: 
`Allowed memory size of 268435456 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 92 bytes)`
Function is able to handle files under 1MB but for files greater than 1MB it fails.
I have asked server administrators to increase memory limit and now no memory errors are visible but still it is not able to fetch all JSON.


I have gone through many post and questions but couldn't find/understood anything useful. Also it is my first attempt to write such function, so any help/guidance will be appreciated.

**EDIT**
Added code for function used

```
function create_post_from_json($json_key) {

    $json_options = get_option('json_file_data');
    $obj = wp_remote_retrieve_body(wp_remote_get($json_options[$json_key]['url'],array( 'timeout' => -1 )));
    $obj = json_decode($obj);
    $id_stored = array();
    $new_posts_id_array = array();
    $new_json_posts_id_array = get_option('json_' . $json_options[$json_key]['name'] . "_post_ids");
    $id_stored = get_option('json_' . $json_options[$json_key]['name']);
    if(!$id_stored){$id_stored = [];}
    foreach ($obj->products as $one_post) {
        $post_char_id = $one_post->ID;
        $new_posts_id_array[] = $post_char_id;
        $cat_array = array();

        if (!in_array($post_char_id, $id_stored)) {
            $id_stored[] = $post_char_id;
            update_option('json_' . $json_options[$json_key]['name'], $id_stored);
            $post = array(
                'post_title' => $one_post->name,
                'post_status' => 'publish',
                'post_author' => 1,
                'post_content' => $one_post->description,
                'post_type' => 'destinations',
            );

            $new_post_id = wp_insert_post($post); //post id
    return true;
}
```

Comment: Once I broke a large file in smaller chunks to increase speed. And it worked well. Is it possible for you to somehow break that file in smaller chunks and retrieve only the chunk you need at one time?

Comment: No, I have no control over incoming data. I wish they had some pagination kind of system.

Comment: So the `wp_remote_get` does not get all your data? I'm trying to understand where the code breaks... Also, how many times do you call `create_post_from_json`?

Comment: On line `json_decode($obj)` it breaks with memory limit exhausted error

Comment: Ok maybe replacing that line with something else would work. Like writing your own function that reads the json and extracts only the key you want. I know that looping through a string is not memory intensive. Would that be possible?

Comment: ... I think that the `json_decode` function is recursive, which could cause problems with large variables, and that would explain your memory problem.

Comment: So I need to create another function which will decode JSON as string?
I have not worked with files much but I will definitely give it a try. Thanks

Comment: It is worth a try. Speed would be affected obviously, but at least you'll have a starting point (in case it works).

Answer (score 0):

Chances are your script might be running out of time.

You could increase the max execution time using `set_time_limit(100); // 100 seconds`

Or to make it indefinite, use `set_time_limit(0);`

**Note:** Set the time on top of your script.

Comment: Done that, I have used `set_time_limit(0);` but error is due to memory limit.

Comment: Then its more of a memory consumption issue. Can you update the question with your code?